# Matching 2 date columns with unequal length

Tags: r, date

i have the following sample of data

```
X <- c("11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016","14/12/2016","15/12/2016","16/12/2016", "17/12/2016")
Y <- c("11/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "18/12/2016")
```

the output i want is something like this

```
X                        Y
11/12/2016         11/12/2016     
12/12/2016             NA
13/12/2016         13/12/2016 
14/12/2016         14/12/2016 
15/12/2016             NA
16/12/2016             NA
17/12/2016             NA
```

i have tried the following code but not getting the desired output

```
> X <- as.Date(data$X)
> Y <- as.Date(data$Y)
> Z <- NA
> for (i in 1:length(X)) {
+ if(X[i] == Y){
+ Z <- Y}
+ else NA }
```

Comment: Your output does not match your `X` and `Y` input

Comment: Well, by the data which you have provided you should get error in first line itself. `as.Date(X)`

Comment: sorry my bad. Now edited the input

Comment: Are you just missing a `[i]` in `if(X[i] == Y)`?

Comment: Note that `11/12/2016 = 0.0004546958`. Therefore, it's a `numeric` not a `date`. Set your `date` as string like this `"11/12/2016"`, then convert them as date like this `as.Date("11/12/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")` and finally with your wanted format `format(as.Date("11/12/2016", "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer!

What you want is to "match" the values of one long vector for your other vector. For that, the function `match` is perfect because return the vector position of the matched elements. First, input the data (I added some corrections):

```
# Input data
X <- c("11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016","14/12/2016","15/12/2016","16/12/2016", "17/12/2016")
Y <- c("11/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "18/12/2016")

# Transform into dates
X <- as.Date(X,"%d/%m/%Y")
Y <- as.Date(Y, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then, I create the data.frame `Z` based on the long vector `X` and I add the matched values of the vector Y:

```
# Run function match so you can see what can of output generates
match(x = X, table = Y)

# Create data.frame
Z <- data.frame(X = X, 
                # add matched values
              Y = Y[match(x = X, table = Y)])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

## Your data:

```
> X <- c("11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016","14/12/2016","15/12/2016","16/12/2016", "17/12/2016")
> Y <- c("11/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "18/12/2016")
```

## Creating new vector of NA's and doing the match:

```
> Z<-rep(NA,length(X))
> Z[which(X %in% Y)]<-X[which(X %in% Y)]
> Z
[1] "11/12/2016" NA           "13/12/2016" "14/12/2016" NA           NA           NA
```

## Your data frame:

```
> data.frame(X,Y=Z)
           X          Y
1 11/12/2016 11/12/2016
2 12/12/2016       <NA>
3 13/12/2016 13/12/2016
4 14/12/2016 14/12/2016
5 15/12/2016       <NA>
6 16/12/2016       <NA>
7 17/12/2016       <NA>
```

Comment: You don't need `which`. Other than that, this solution should have been accepted instead of copycat Santi's one. At least you get +1 from me ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, Santi gave as right the other answer despite of I answered first :-(. I really appreciate your +1, It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `merge`:

```
X <- c("11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016","14/12/2016","15/12/2016","16/12/2016", "17/12/2016")
Y <- c("11/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "18/12/2016")

df_X <- data.frame(X)

df_Y <- data.frame(X = Y, Y = Y)

merge(df_X, df_Y, all = TRUE)
```

Or, if you like a `tidyverse`-approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
X <- c("11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016","14/12/2016","15/12/2016","16/12/2016", "17/12/2016")
Y <- c("11/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "18/12/2016")

df_X <- tibble(X)

df_Y <- tibble(X = Y, Y = Y)

full_join(df_X, df_Y)
```

The important part is, that you duplicate your column you want to match and name it accordingly, or use the `by`-argument.